# Почему при старте Mobile Hotspot не могу зайти ни на один сайт с раздающего компьютера?

Tags: windows

Когда активирую Mobile Hotspot, то не могу зайти ни на какой сайт. Ошибка соединение сброшено. Но в то же время, на устройствах, которые подключились, можно заходить везде.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема возникла в обновлении KB5014697 для Windows, а в обновлении KB5014668 исправлена.

Answer (score 0):

Твое устройство подключено к интернету по проводу или через wifi?
если через wifi то вроде так и должно быть. На андроид тоже самое, пока раздаешь точку доступа, подключиться к другой не можешь.